# Usage of through in speaking

Tags: verbs, spoken-english

When and where can I use the word "through" in speaking and writing?

Explain with  an example.

For example, Mahesh is a person's name, there is a situation like this, during a phone call:

> I put you through Mahesh.

Comment: It is quite impossible to describe all the uses of a "function word" like a preposition briefly. A good [**dictionary**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/through) will provide you a starting point. ... *Mahesh* is not an English word, so if you have a specific question about *through mahesh* you will have to translate that word.

Comment: +1, StoneyB. It is impossible to describe all of them. And if the question was about the quoted sentence, then since Mahesh is a person's name, you need to put a comma before _Mahesh_, making it **"I put you through, Mahesh."**

Comment: Agreed with those who voted 'close'. To the OP, Here, it means *I'll get Mahesh on the phone for you.*

@StoneyB *Mahesh* is an Indian name (the OP says that) and not an English word.

Comment: The confusion around *mahesh* could have been avoided if you'd spelled it correctly. The name of a person always starts with a capital letter. Apart from that, what is your question? The word *through* has far too many meanings to list here; look it up in a dictionary to get an idea of what it can mean.

Answer (score 3):

`I put you through Mahesh` is not right.

If you were speaking to Mahesh, then you'd say: `I'll put you through, Mahesh`
If you were speaking to someone else who wants to speak to Mahesh then you'd say:  `I'll put you through to Mahesh`
When you say, `put you through Mahesh`, it sounds you as though you will physically put (the person you are talking to) through Mahesh (*which is kind of dirty or disturbing*).

As a third person you'd say: "`Kindly put Ramesh through **to** Mahesh`".

Secondly, the applicable uses of the word "through" are vast. A dictionary and lots of examples will be the quickest way to learn this.

Comment: If one were talking to Mahesh, it would be perfectly normal to say "I'll put you through, Mahesh" to communicate that one was about to transfer the call to a predetermined third party.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung : ahh, true, that's a valid scenario, i'll add that in the answer

Comment: And actually *"I put you through, Mahesh*" would also be perfectly valid if Mahesh had been wondering who had put him through yesterday.

Comment: @Jim : ah, yes, that too but when it comes to written English it will be "`I put you through, Mahesh!`" but i'll edit this into the answer as well. hm... now how do i phrase it?